# Passing argument from heap to function

Tags: c++

Here is my question.
I have a pointer with allocated memory to some class:

```
Class *pClass = new Class();
```

Now I want to pass this object to some function, wich will use this object just to copy it and will not modify it. The question is how to correctly pass the object?

```
void someFunc (const Class &_class);
{
    Class *pClassInFunc = new Class (_class);
    ...
}
...
someFunc (*pClass)
```

or

```
void someFunc (const Class *_class);
{
    Class *pClassInFunc = new Class (*_class);
    ...
}
...
someFunc (pClass)
```

or

```
void someFunc (Class _class);
{
    // just use _class since it's already a copy
    ...
}
...
someFunc (*pClass)
```

I've choosed the first way, but it looks strange to me, smth tells me that it's not correct. The second one looks more C-style (or not?). And the last one creates a copy in the stack, which is not desireable.
So, what is the best solution?
Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: just saw, I forgot * before pClassInFunc. Corrected, sorry.

Comment: Yes. How about using the first way, but do you really need to allocate the class using `new`? Why not just `Class nClass; someFunc(nClass);` (using pass by const ref)

Comment: The first two snippets aren't valid C++.

Comment: @Porkbutts: This class holds around 3000 double variables. I thought it is more wisely to keep it in heap.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Why? All three methods compile and work without any errors.

Comment: @OggY: well yes, after you edited the question... never mind.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry for that stupid mistake, it was late night =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I vote for the last approach. Design your function so that it doesn't care exactly how the calling code allocated the object. If it wants a copy, take the object by value. It makes the intentions clearer to the user.

It also allows the caller to move from their object if they don't need it any more. If you were to take a reference to `const` and *then* copy it, that wouldn't be an option (you can't move from a `const` object).

If the calling code can, it should avoid dynamically allocating the object in the first place. Then, if you choose to take the argument by value, it is very simple to pass the object.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Why should I avoid dynamic allocating? I thought it's always a good idea to keep big (20kb is big?) objects in heap then in stack. Especially when they live the whole programm runtime.

Comment: @OggY Okay, 20KB is fairly large for a stack object, but not too large. You typically have a limit of 1MB. If the copy is only for the duration of a single function, I wouldn't worry about it. If you're going to have many of these copies on the stack at one time, you might want to do it a different way. In that case, I'd vote for the first method.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made my desition. I'll keep long-live object in heap, but will provide a stack copy to the func since it's fast enough.

Comment: Keep in mind that dynamic allocation is very expensive; every call to 'new' or 'malloc' gives up control to the OS to ask for some memory before it can proceed.

Comment: Ok ... You don,t trust me ... Then let's see what Herb Sutter to say about this...http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects     in any case copying a 3000 float class does not make for good design ... Or practice ...

Comment: @MihaiSebea There's a difference. In that case, there's not going to be a copy. In this case, there is. If there's going to be a copy anyway, take it by value. This at least allows for moving.

Comment: apparently the question has been edited but in any case ..passing be value is usually wrong ...and a codebase should be consistent ...